# Connect Hbase API via proxy or SSH tunnel

Tags: java, proxy, hbase, ssh-tunnel

Can somebody give me a description how can i connect to Hbase API via SSH tunnel, or proxy? I tunneled all necessary ports, but when it connected to Hbase Zookeeper could not resolved the DNS name in Hbase Master.

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far.

Comment: Check your networking: firewall and DNS configuration. Hosts should resolve host names to IP addresses and reverse.